# Is there a way to combine multiple columns in a table?

Tags: support, markdown, tables

I would like to create a table that has some combined columns.
Something like this:

```
| title 1 | title 2 | title 3 |
|:-------:|:-------:|:-------:|
|     info 1 & 2    |  info 3 |
|  info 4 |  info 5 |  info 6 |
```

Comment: No; *You can't merge cells or rows.*

Comment: Is that a limitation of Markdown, [not HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477927/combine-cells-in-an-html-table/4477934#4477934)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Not sure it's technically a limitation of either. The version of MD you're using for the table code determines what's possible. There's certainly versions of table MD that do allow merging both rows and columns and a variety of other options. That's not what we have enabled for a variety of reasons, most basic is that, as far as I'm aware, the versions were not as common or standard as they are now - but I don't think they're completely common either way as Tables aren't an official part of CommonMark.

Comment: There's a long discussion of it on the CommonMark Discourse - [here](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/tables-in-pure-markdown/81/165).